# how SVG curveTo ( C ) works?

Tags: math, svg, bezier

I need your help , I am confused a little.

My question is how SVG curveTo works, really I can't understand.

look for this example

```
<svg height="400" width="400">
 <path d="M 200 90 C 200  90 0 0 90  300 " stroke="black" fill="none" stroke-width="3"/>
</svg>
```

this code draws this shape

[image]

but really I can't understand how that done , I can't understand how the curve identified and what control points are and what 0 0 coordinate represents in my example.

Comment: http://www.w3.org/Graphics/SVG/IG/resources/svgprimer.html#path_C

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You are drawing a *Cubic Bezier* curve (with *two* control points). But one of the control points has the same coordinates as the starting point.

1. Move (`M`) to (200,90).
2. Draw a *Cubic* (`C`) Bezier Curve

   a. starting at current position `(200,90)`
   b. first control point at `(200,90)` - *same* as starting point
   c. second control point at `(0,0)`
   d. ending at `(90,300)`

Comment: Where do you see the ending coordinates at (90, 30) ? I see `90  300` at the end. Did you mean for your letter d `(90,300)`?

Comment: Yes. That's correct. It should be 300, not 30. Thank you. I'll fix it.

Answer (score 1):

Bezier curves are a bit tricky to get the sense of. Perhaps the section at http://www.w3.org/Graphics/SVG/IG/resources/svgprimer.html#path_C might help, and maybe the section before that on quadratic Beziers. As the earlier poster pointed out, having your start point and the control point coincident makes your case a bit odder, still, perhaps.